# Reverse Proxy to multiple ports/servers in Apache2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I want to forward a single request to multiple ports on the same server.  I tried using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse with different configurations on the same VirtualHost file but it only forwards to one port.  I also tried using proxy_balancer but still only forwards the request to a single port.  Is there something I am missing or maybe this is not the best way to accomplish this?

code:

```
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
            #1st port
            BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8000/
            #2nd port
            BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8001/
            ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    </Proxy>
    <Location /app>
            ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/
            ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/
    </Location>
```

I also tried:

```
    <Location /app>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    </Location>
    <Location /app>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8001/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8001/
    </Location>
```

Comment: How many different clients have you used for testing? Apache might route the requests based on the client IP address, and if you test using the same client, the request is always routed to the same endpoint.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've only used curl cli and a vscode rest client... why would that affect the outcome? I need to forward ANY request to all ports/servers, not just one

Comment: Apache2 cannot do this, it is not a designed use case. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Which response you would send back to the client? The response from port `8000` or one from port `8001`? How would you decide which response to send?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I see. I dont need to send a response.  I have apps running on each port that do something with the data (POST) they receive.

Comment: Then you need to find some other solution for this. For example, create a script that reads the POST request from clients, sends 200 OK response back (I assume you are using HTTP protocol). Then the script will send the data to each backend separately.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes this is what I'm doing now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you managed to find the solution for this issue? We have same requirements in our env. Could you please share the solution. Thank you

Comment: @Ram I wrote a script that forwards to each backend see Tero 's comment... I will post a sample script which worked for me to answer the question..

Answer (score 0):

Sample script using ReactPHP server forwards response to multiple ports..

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$ports = ["8001", "8002", "8003"];

$http_client = new \Clue\React\Buzz\Browser($loop);

$server = new \React\Http\Server($loop, function (\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request) use ($http_client, $clients){
    # forward requests to various apps on ports

    $body = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    foreach($ports as $port){
        $http_client->post("http://127.0.0.1:" . $port, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'], $body);
    }
    //echo $request->getBody();

    return new \React\Http\Message\Response(200, ["Content-Type" => "text/plain"], "request forwarded to ports\n");
});




$socket = new \React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:8000', $loop);

$server->listen($socket);

echo 'Listening on ' . str_replace('tcp', 'http', $socket->getAddress()) . PHP_EOL;

$loop->run();
```